# sed - using array to build regex

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm having problems constructing regular expression from array of strings, for use in `sed` command.

Here's an example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function join { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

array=("foo" "bar" "baz")
regex=$(join "\|" "${array[@]}") # foo|bar|baz

echo "foo bar baz" | sed "s/${regex}/replaced/g"
```

I'm expecting this to output `replaced replaced replaced`, but it's returning `foo bar baz` since this regex is not hitting anything. The pipes in the regex are not being escaped correctly here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` needs to be escaped in basic regex syntax. Either use extended syntax:

```
sed -r "s/${regex}/replaced/g"          # GNU sed. With BSD sed, use -E
```

Or build the regex so that it is `foo\|bar\|baz`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
regex=$(join '|' "${array[@]}")
```

Since `IFS` accepts only one character.

Then use (for BSD):

```
echo "foo bar baz" | sed -E "s/${regex}/replaced/g"
```

OR for Linux:

```
echo "foo bar baz" | sed -r "s/${regex}/replaced/g"
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to avoid using extended regex option in `sed` then refactor your `join` function like this:

```
join() { sep="$1"; shift; echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "$sep%s" "$@"; }
```

Then use it as:

```
regex=$(join '\|' "${array[@]}")
echo "foo bar baz" | sed "s/${regex}/replaced/g"
replaced replaced replaced
```